# Create and deploy Vaadin 7 Portlet in Liferay 7

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin, vaadin7, liferay-7

With Liferay 6.x it is very easy to develop and deploy some Vaadin 7 portlets. Because of all changes in Liferay 7, my Portlets won't work. I didn't even get a single "Hello World" Vaadin portlet to run.

I've already read the article from "Sampsa Sohlman" ([Link](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/sampsa.sohlman/blog/-/blogs/double-seven-vaadin-7-with-liferay-2)), but it won't work with the newest Version of Liferay.

My question: Is there any chance to get an example Vaadin 7 Liferay 7 "Hello World" Portlet?

I'm grateful for every answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay's message board thread has now answer for you :)

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/76582064

In a nutshel (copying the most important from the above source) You need to build:

https://github.com/sammso/vaadin/tree/manifest-fix

Then you need to build :

https://github.com/sammso/com.vaadin.liferay

You can also try older version https://github.com/sammso/com.vaadin.liferay/tree/7.6.7 that is still with old package paths etc.
Also https://github.com/sammso/vaadin/tree/manifest-fix is now at https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin and will be released on next version.

In order to build the current version you need to manually edit the POM.xml 
Change the following dependency in all the `pom.xml` that it occurs:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
<version>${liferay.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to the next.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
<version>2.7.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: I tried to build using the sources https://github.com/sammso/com.vaadin.liferay however I am using liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga2. Is there something I need to change? I can see in the parent pom-xml that portal-service is a dependency. I  had the impression that it had been replaced by portal-kernel. See https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/whats-changed-and-what-hasnt

Comment: Searching in the maven central I can only find on v7.0 portal service, portal-service.7.0.0-nightly (from 08-Oct-2014) there is no version portal-service.7.0.0-m6.jar or portal-service.7.0.0-ga2.jar.

Comment: In order to build the project the following change has to be done:Changing the following dependency:
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
<version>${liferay.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
to the next, would suffice to build the project.
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
<version>2.7.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a link to develop a portlet in vaadin 7 [link](https://web.liferay.com/fr/web/26526/blog/-/blogs/developing-a-portlet-in-vaadin-7) The author loaded the project into his own github account, you can access it from [here](https://github.com/dnebinger/vaadin-sample-portlet).  Feel free to clone it, fork it, modify as you'd like.

If you have the Vaadin 7 Control Panel installed and you've deployed the LazyPagedContainer Add On, you can download and deploy the vaadin-sample-portlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war [link](https://web.liferay.com/documents/26528/48600753/vaadin-sample-portlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/70acad3b-c875-4e24-b820-e7507acd58b9)  file directly from this blog.

Comment: This is for Vaadin 7 and Liferay 6, Liferay 7 is very different.